# What is the basis for the quantifier notation?

Tags: reference-request, notation

The symbols $\forall, \exists$ are the ones officially used to denote universal and existential quantifiers respectively. I understand that the choice of $\exists$ was made by Peano, while of $\forall$ by Gentzen, and apparantly propagated by [Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#Notation). However, I'm observing some pitfalls in that notation.

First they are turned Latin symbols of the first letters of "All; Exists", so they are language bound, which shouldn't be a feature of a logical symbol. I'm of the personal impression that logical symbols are ought to be language free, and they in some sense and to some extent are to be self explanatory, which I don't see $\forall, \exists $ fulfilling.

The second objection is that, having a letterlike character (even if turned) makes one confuse them with symbols holding some particular extra-logical content! and so in some sense violates the generality of logical symbols, and this in some sense gives an impression of some impredicament or glitching in logical flow, that is, it is not as flawless as the other connectives appear.

The third objection is that the use of an opposite layout of a letter seems in some sense to be defying normal presentation of matters, which logic shouldn't be (in at least my personal opinion) denoted with, since logic is generally ought to be a *tool securing correct form of reasoning*, so we ought not to represent main concepts of it, like quantification, by symbols put in opposite direction to how they are customarily used in ordinary language. If we look at [Frege](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/#ComStaGen)'s symbols we see them both self-explanatory and language-free, but they are to some degree complex and meant to embody other connectives with them, which adds some combinatorial complexity to them. I think the display of the main logical connectives ($\neg, \uparrow, \downarrow, \to , \land, \lor, \leftrightarrow$) is actually excellent! So, I don't see that they need to be complexed forming further *individual* logical symbols through having many components.

In my own personal opinion I think we are to use an arrow notation to represent quantification, and I suggest the following: $$ \overset {x} \uparrow \qquad\text{and}\qquad \underset{x} \downarrow $$ to represent universal and existential quantification respectively. Or if one prefer the ordinary horizontal placing of quantified symbols, then: $$\uparrow \!\! x \qquad\text{and}\qquad \downarrow \!\! x$$So we'll have $$(\forall x \, \exists y \, (x=y)) \iff (\overset {x} \uparrow \, \underset {y} \downarrow (x=y))$$ or horizontally placed: $$(\forall x \, \exists y \, (x=y)) \iff (\uparrow \! x,  \downarrow \! y \, (x=y))$$

I think this is: (1) language free, (2) explanatory, (3) flawless, (4) general, and (5) normal, and moreover (6) elegant.

So, my question is twofold:

> Has the traditional symbolism of quantication been subject to this kind of criticism, and proved to meet all concerns or at least most?

> Are the above suggested symbols acceptable or at least meeting the conditions alluded to? Or even been suggested before?

Comment: I've seen some paper use $\bigwedge_x$ and $\bigvee_x$ for $\forall x$ and $\exists x$ respectively, which is perfectly sensible as they are an internal form of conjunction and disjunction. (It might introduce an ambiguity with an external form, esp. in infinitary languages, or simply if $p_1\land\cdots\land p_n$ is written $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n p_i$, but this can be lifted by decorating the symbol or the indices in some way.)

Comment: FWIW, many other symbols are also derived from natural languages: + is a form of Latin "et", $\sum$ and $\prod$ are Greek letters, $\int$ is an elongated S for Latin "summa". I don't buy the argument that this is a bad thing for a mathematical symbol.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, yes, I saw this notation, it definitely represents an advantage over the customary ones, but there is some aesthetic problem with it. Also, it is a little bit glitching since it is a symbol used for other connectives, and so to some extent glitching, but it is indeed language free, very explanatory, general, normal, but not flawless, not elegant.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen, I'm not speaking about mathematical symbols in general, I'm speaking about logic in particular. The other mathematical symbols does hold a content that is extra-logical, so you can let them be language bound, I've alluded somewhat to that issue. But for logic in particular, the quantifier symbolization doesn't parallel the rest of the connectives. I'm speaking about a very paricular context here, and not about any mathematical symbol. The issue here is about the best symbolization of LOGICAL concepts. To me, the quantifiers are not symbolized in the BEST manner; the rest are!

Comment: The "best" notation is the one that best fulfils the only real job of any notation: To transport meaning and understanding from one mind to another. And this kind of [bike-shedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) does nothing to further that goal. In fact, going against *any* established notation at first only hinders the interpersonal transport of meaning and understanding and these kinds fundamental notational shifts often do not happen at all if the new notation is not *significantly* better at expressing the intended meaning and transporting understanding.

Comment: I don’t buy the claim that the new notation is self-explanatory. It’s just as arbitrary as the existing notation; the one, and only, self-explanatory aspect of $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ is that the notation suggests they are *related to each other*. Nothing more. (For that matter, the standard propositional connectives are not self-explanatory either; again, the only thing the notation makes clear is that $\land$ and $\lor$ are related.)

Comment: Concerning the actual questions: The part of the suggested notation being "acceptable" seems a bit opinion-based. One could, of course, address it from practical grounds. As a practical matter, I'd like to ask for clarification: does the suggestion entail that $\uparrow$ would work *both* as the logical NAND (Sheffer stroke) *and* as the universal quantifier? This might be confusing. (Likewise for $\downarrow$, logical NOR and existential quantifier.)

Comment: @JohannesHahn, I see what you mean. But, your criterion is *external* to the subject matter itself, it is related to how its been used rather to the internal particulars of the subject matter itself; as such the argument by estalishment is historical and circumstantial, I'm asking about "internal" criteria of scrutinzing a notation and in particular about a specific item in logic, that is quantification. I need criterions related to quantification itself, being so general logic item, if the notation is flawless , is it in alignment with the rest of notation for the connectives, elegant, etc.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen. No, it has nothing to do with NAND, I've put the quantified variable on top and below to make the distinction. But I agree that this would be somewhat a source of confusion. I don't see NAND much used in articles though, so perhaps this alleviate matters, but I agree this is a point of weakness there, but I think its less than the same concern with the notation spoken about by Gro-Tsen

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, if you have noticed I've written "explanatory" in the conditions, I mean it is more into the meaning of *over all* and *under certain* gestures which are linked to universal and existential quantification, the uparrow gives an impression of a *lot*, while the down arrow of *less*, there is some relation, while with the turned symbols the relation is not clearly related with any notion of quantity, its not even clear that they are opposing. Here It's more explanatory than the usual ones, however $\bigwedge; \bigvee$ might be more explanatory. Its not self explaining, Yes.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar You misunderstand. I'm saying there *are no internal criteria* ! All of what notation does and is supposed to do is external. It's only function is to facilitate communication between humans and that's the measuring stick against which every notation has to be compared.

Comment: @JohannesHahn, well in that sense then for this particular issue of course we won't expect a major breakthrough in communication just by changing two symbols, so per your maxim of externality, the whole matter would be trivial. I don't like this point of view. I do think that there must be *internal* criteria about symbolisim, and that symbols must best capture the properties of what they are symbolizing, and the more they capture the more ideal they are (even if not used ever).

Comment: If there were anything *internal* to it, then you should be able to at least communicate, if not agree upon such an internal criterion with super-intelligent jellyfish under the ice of some exo-moon or non-corporeal energy beings of the ninth dimension, right? Presumably, they are familiar with and able to use the logic behind our notation just as much, if not more so than we are. So anything that if there is anything "internal" to logic itself then it should apply both to humans and aliens, shouldn't it?

Comment: re: up and downvotes: Although I personally very much disagree with the suggestion, I do think it is a valid question, and even on-topic; it is about notation, and who else than research mathematicians would be the best audience for that kind of question?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to address this part of the question:

> Are the above suggested symbols acceptable or at least meeting the conditions alluded to?

I am understanding that this refers to these conditions:

> (1) language free, (2) explanatory, (3) flawless, (4) general, and (5) normal, and moreover (6) elegant

(1) Yes, it seems obviously language free; arrows are pretty much universal. (Whether this is good, bad or neutral, is another matter.)

(2) I have difficulty seeing it as explanatory. How does an up-arrow represent "all"? The one explanatory aspect (mentioned by Emil Jeřábek) is that the two symbols look like they are related, which is good. (Similarly, $\forall$ and $\exists$ look related *because both are upside down*.)

**EDIT:** Seeing the explanation in comments ("uparrow gives an impression of a lot, while the down arrow of less"), I see there is a connection with the [MORE IS UP](https://metaphor.icsi.berkeley.edu/pub/en/index.php/Metaphor:MORE_IS_UP) and [LESS IS DOWN](https://metaphor.icsi.berkeley.edu/pub/en/index.php/Metaphor:LESS_IS_DOWN) metaphors, which are very common in human languages. However, it requires one further step of abstraction: "more" or "a lot" is then meant to suggest "all", and "less" or "little" to suggest "at least some". Here the chain of metaphors is becoming too tenuous to my taste.

(3) I don't understand what "flawless" means in this context. Isn't any arbitrary self-consistent notation flawless in itself? In some sense, notation is arbitrary (or as one my teachers said: you could as well draw a little dog).

(4) It seems that "general" has some special meaning in this question. Ordinarily, I would say that notation is "general" if it can be applied to all relevant cases, without somehow becoming impossible or confusing in some cases. (For a counterexample, if I defined a positional numeral system with base $b>10$ so that the digits for $10,11,12,\ldots$ are the English letters $A,B,C,\ldots$, one could say my notation is not general because it runs out of letters after $Z$.) In this sense, the proposed $\uparrow \downarrow$ notation is just as general as the conventional $\forall \exists$, not more, not less.

But here "general" seems to be an aesthetic judgment that prefers abstract figures (such as arrows, squares) over letters, because letters suggest "extra-logical content". I get the impression that this refers to letters being *ordinarily* used for variables, functions etc. But I fail to see *practical* improvement: although the conventional $\forall \exists$ are based on letters, their special upside-down format keeps them quite safely apart from any of your ordinary variable names such as $A$ and $E$. So there is no trouble with "generality" in that sense.

(5) I guess "normal" refers to "following typical conventions of notation, so as to fit well with other notation and not cause confusion". There is something not quite normal: putting the variable on top of the symbol. Although mathematics contains examples of all kinds of funny vertical, horizontal and diagonal placement of symbols, one thing that seems somewhat common is that "big" prefix operators put the indexing symbol *below* the operator (or as a subscript if tight for vertical space), as in
$$
\prod_i \sum_j ij.
$$
Although the current practice with $\forall x \exists y$ usually puts the variable on the same line, I would not be surprised to see it under the operator. Putting it on top seems deviant.

(6) Elegance is very much opinion-based.

Comment: Yes, there is a relation, both written in apposite manner to the normal way of writting in English, (and they are supposed to be symbols capturing LOGIC, a tool securing correct reasoning), but they are not opposite each other, one is upside down, the other is right-left turned, the symbols themselves are different (I mean a part of the turning style) so they are not opposing faces of one concept that is quantification. Regarding operators, there are indeed instances in logic where we put matters on top of the symbols. So this is not abnormal here.

Comment: Well, you can pick your choice of how A becomes $\forall$ and E becomes $\exists$. But if you choose $180^\circ$ rotation then both work in the same way.

Comment: if the down up placing of the quantified symbol appears awkward, then we can use the ordinary placing, but use commas to resolve the confusion with the sheffer and Nor operators. To compare with usual  notation see: $$\uparrow \! \!A, \, \downarrow \! \! X, \, \uparrow \!\! Y \, (Y \in X \leftrightarrow Y \in A \land \phi(Y,A))$$

$$\forall A, \exists X, \forall Y \, (Y \in X \leftrightarrow Y \in A \land \phi(Y,A))$$, To me, I see the customary notation feels quite heavy by comparison,  what I call as glitchy, stumbling, or in other words: not flawless.

Comment: One further problem is that up and down arrows have plenty of other uses in mathematics, for example in limits (approaching from below and above) and in partial orders (up-set and down-set). I admit that $\vee$ and $\wedge$ are also overloaded.

Comment: Agreed! And as usual the context would make the difference. To me logical concepts are the simplest of concepts, the non-logical ones are heavier, notation like $\forall; \exists$, being letters, are heavy to me, they provide the impression of holding some extra-logical information, unlike arrows which seems to be only linked to streaming of information, and do not confer the impression of carrying particular extra-logical meaning, therefore I call them as *light* symbols, or flawless. And thanks for your answer!